# is there any way of handling 300 range status codes in API request responses in angular?

Tags: angular, ajax, api, rest

I have to handle status code 300 as response of api request and after send request postman and browser network tab shows response as shown image i try to handle request in res and error scopes but cant catch it. is there any way to handle it?

[image]

Comment: are you saying its not entering both error and response call back?

Comment: actually i need to frontend level handling like open modal popup with result data receive.